# Replace Characters in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to replace the last character in an excel cell. I am using

```
=IF(RIGHT(B2,1)="W", LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-1) &"U", B2)
```

This works to replace W with U, as I want. The problem I am having is that I need to replace any A as well. Is there a way to do an IF W or IF A, replace with U?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (Incorrect):

```
=IF(RIGHT(B2,1)="W" OR RIGHT(B2,1)="A", LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-1) & "U", B2)
```

As per @Oberling

```
=IF(OR(RIGHT(B2,1)="A", RIGHT(B2,1)="W"), LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-1) & "U", B2)
```

As per @Barry

```
=IF(OR(RIGHT(B2)={"W","A"}), LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-1) & "U", B2)
```

The second two were tested in Excel 2013

Comment: `OR(RIGHT(B2,1)="W", RIGHT(B2,1)="A")`

Comment: The piece that Orbling gave works. Thank you guys so much for your help.

Comment: You can also use `OR(RIGHT(B2)={"W","A"})`